# Promises and Await/Async with TS and Office.js

Tags: typescript, promise, async-await, office-js

What I am attempting to do is get the range of the bound cells after prompting the user to make a binding.  I am combining the Office 2013 API with the 2016 API to do this.

My Prompt to the user:

```
bind(bindingName: string, type: string): Promise<string> {
        let bindType: Office.BindingType;
        if(type != 'data.frame' && type != 'vector') {
            bindType = Office.BindingType.Text;
        } else {
            bindType = Office.BindingType.Matrix;
        }
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            Office.context.document.bindings.addFromPromptAsync(bindType, {id: bindingName}, (result: Office.AsyncResult) => {
                if(result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
                    resolve(bindingName);
                } 
            })
        })
    }
```

Getting the range of the binding:

```
async getRange(name:string): Promise<string> {
        return await Excel.run(async (context) => {
            let binding = context.workbook.bindings.getItem(name);
            let range = binding.getRange();
            range.load("address");

            await context.sync()

            return range.address;
        })
    }
```

Combining the call to output the range:

```
this.excelService.bind(name, type)
      .then(result => this.excelService.getRange(result))
      .then(result => {
        this.feedback = result;
      })
```

Feedback results in being an empty string which leads me to believe I've screwed up the promise structure somehow.  I'm new to TypeScript, so if someone could point out where I might be going wrong, I'd appreciate it.  Thanks!

Comment: If you could create a Script Lab snippet for this, it will be much easier to answer it (and only need to tweak a bit of your code, rather than needing to create a snippet from scratch)

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky-Microsoft https://gist.github.com/brandonkoch6/8d0ec0c8d8eebb160088ecef040b6b8c what's strange is that this works fine in scriptlab and occasionally works in my sideloaded Excel add-in written in Angular.  But for some reason, it doesn't always work which leads me to believe that the promises are getting screwed up some how?

Comment: Hm, if it always works in Script Lab, I'm guessing it's something about the way you're hooking up your Angular code... but I'm not sure I am of as much help there.  Your code looks right (other than the lack of error-handling, in both the callback of `addFromPromptAsync`, and in a lack of a `catch` statement for the `this.excelService.bind` call.  Best of luck!

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky-Microsoft Is there any sort of incompatibility with the latest version of Angular? I've built mine with the same architecture as the github.com/OfficeDev/Word-Add-in-Angular2-StyleChecker so I'm a bit confused since my architecture is fairly simple. Creating the binding always resolves successfully in my local app. It's the getting the range or really any of the calls from the new 2016 API that occasionally do not work.  I'm using Excel 2016, which I assume would work just fine.  Is there anything I should be checking for?  The inconsistencies between the API calls seem odd.

Comment: When they "don't work", do they throw an error?  I am always suspicious of code that omits error handling... You can always use OfficeHelpers.Utilities.log from the Office Js Helpers github project for a good API-tailored logging utility.  And just ensure that you have "catch" blocks at the end of each promise, and that you are not breaking the promise chain (which it didn't look like you were, but just pointing it out just in case).  I don't see how angular or any other framework would be effecting the APIs.

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky-Microsoft Yeah, I have them wrapped in try/catch blocks.  I omitted those from the ScriptLab for simplicity.  So, I run those same two methods twice.  Once for an input parameter the user needs to select.  The second time for an output parameter the user selects.  The first time, it gets the range of their selected cells just fine.  The second time, the binding occurs correctly.  However, when it uses the exact same getRange() method, I receive this error:

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky-Microsoft
{ "name": "OfficeExtension.Error", "code": "InvalidArgument", "message": "The argument is invalid or missing or has an incorrect format.", "traceMessages": [], "innerError": null, "debugInfo": { "code": "InvalidArgument", "message": "The argument is invalid or missing or has an incorrect format.", "errorLocation": "Binding.getRange" }, "stack": "InvalidArgument: The argument is invalid or missing or has an incorrect format.\n at Anonymous function (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/excel-win32-16.01.js:21:202148)\n at ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky-Microsoft Had to cut off the error message slightly to it would fit in the comment.  I emailed you the full error.

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky-Microsoft The error message would lead you to believe that I'm passing incorrect arguments.  However, I'm just passing the name of the binding that was just created successfully and then trying to get the range on it as shown in the snippet.

Comment: I wonder if the problem is with the binding type?  You can only get the range of a range (matrix if 2013 terminology) binding..,

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky-Microsoft
I wondered that as well and hardcoded it to a Matrix binding type for all last night, but it didn't seem to fix the problem.  I was still receiving that same error message.  I wonder if since they're both asynchronous calls, that perhaps Angular does some sort of micro management on that and the two different calls can end up in different execution contexts so that the binding doesn't exist in the new execution context when it goes to get the binding and getRange().  So the invalid argument is the binding itself because it didn't exist in the context?

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky-Microsoft So maybe it works sometimes because both calls end up in the same context and then doesn't work others because they're not?

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky-Microsoft When I was looking at in my apartment this morning, it wasn't working.  However, when I got to the office and I loaded it up, it appeared as if the cache of saved credentials had been flushed from Excel, and now it's working perfectly.  Is there some sort of caching behavior within Excel that might be affecting it?